# Scala Set intersection performance

Tags: scala, performance

Using Scala's `scala.collection.Set[T]`. Given a small set `s` with only a few elements and another big set `b` with lots of elements, is there any performance difference between:

```
s & b // s intersect b
```

and

```
b & s // b intersect s.
```

If yes, which is the fastest?

Comment: "If yes, which is the fastest?" -- why not benchmark it and see?

Comment: You can use `filter`  to take advantage of the size difference to get better performance: `smallSet filter bigSet`. This will make a new set by adding the items in `smallSet` are in `bigSet` without you needing to check each element of `bigSet`. `&` may do this under the hood but better to be explicit in my opinion.

Comment: @morsecodist; According to [the source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.7/src/library/scala/collection/GenSetLike.scala#L1), `intersect()` actually _is_ the `filter()` op.

Comment: @jwvh It is probably overriden, as the implementation which is called eventually is `scala.collection.immutable.HashSet.HashTrieSet#intersect0` and looks quite complex to me. Based on my rough benchmarking its peformance is comparable to `a filter b` and it is much faster than `b filter a`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is: it's complicated.

The default implementation of an immutable set is [scala.collection.immutable.Set](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Set.scala#L65). This has [special cases](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Set.scala#L84) for sizes 1 to 4. As soon as you have more than 4 elements, it will use [scala.collection.immutable.HashSet](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/HashSet.scala#L213).

## Very small s (1..4)

So let's say you have a large set `b` and a small set `s`, with `s` containing <4 elements.

Then it will make a **large** difference:

`b & s` will filter all elements of `b` against membership in `s` and therefore takes b.count * s.count equality comparisons. Since b is large this will be quite slow.

`s & b` will filter the few elements of `s` against a membership in `b`, which is s.length times a hashing and an equality comparison if the hashes match (remember b is a HashSet). Since is is small this should be very fast.

## Small s (n>4)

As soon as `s` is larger than 4 elements, it *also* will be a HashSet. Intersection for HashSets is written in a symmetric and very efficient way. It will combine the tree structures of `s` and `b` and perform equality comparisons when the hashes match. It will use maximum structural sharing. E.g. if `b` contains all elements of `s`, the result will be *the same instance* as s, so no objects will be allocated.

## General advice

If you just write generic code where you don't care much about high performance, it is fine to use the default implementations such as `scala.collection.Set`. However, if you care about performance characteristics it is preferable to use a *concrete* implementation. E.g. if `s` and `b` are declared as `scala.collection.immutable.HashSet`, you will have consistent high performance independent of order, provided that you have a good hash function.

Answer (score 3):

The generic implementation seen in the `GenSetLike` using `filter` is overriden for `HashSet` with an implementation which looks quite complex to me (see [scala.collection.immutable.HashSet.HashTrieSet#intersect0](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/8684ae833dcfeac6107343fcca5501301e509eef/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/HashSet.scala#L669)). Based on my rough benchmark its performance is similar for both `a & b` and `b & a` and it is similar to the performance of `a filter b`, which is an order of magnitude faster than `b filter a`. My testing code is:

```
object Sets extends App {

  def time[R](block: => R): R = {
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    val result = block    // call-by-name
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time: " + (t1 - t0)/1e6 + "ms")
    result
  }

  val a = (0 until 10000 by 1).toSet      //smaller data
  val b = (0 until 1000000 by 2).toSet


  time {a & b}
  time {b & a}
  time {a & b}
  time {b & a}
  time {a & b}
  time {b & a}

  println("Filter")

  time {a filter b}
  time {b filter a}
  time {a filter b}
  time {b filter a}
  time {a filter b}
  time {b filter a}
}
```

Result is:

```
Elapsed time: 6.990442ms
Elapsed time: 4.25017ms
Elapsed time: 4.1089ms
Elapsed time: 4.480789ms
Elapsed time: 3.71588ms
Elapsed time: 3.160159ms
Filter
Elapsed time: 7.781613ms
Elapsed time: 68.33023ms
Elapsed time: 5.858472ms
Elapsed time: 42.491131ms
Elapsed time: 2.982364ms
Elapsed time: 52.762474ms
```

Answer (score -1):

Let us create two sets as per the condition mentioned

```
   val a = (0 until 10000 by 1).toSet      //smaller data
   val b = (0 until 1000000 by 2).toSet    //Relatively larger data
```

we can define a time function to check the execution time as below

```
def time[R](block: => R): R = {
    val t0 = System.nanoTime()
    val result = block    // call-by-name
    val t1 = System.nanoTime()
    println("Elapsed time: " + (t1 - t0) + "ns")
    result
}
```

Now we can check the intersection conditon

```
scala> time {a & b}
Elapsed time: 5895220ns
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(892, 5810, 8062, ..)

scala> time {b & a}
Elapsed time: 6038271ns
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(892, 5810, 8062, ...)
```

So by this we can conclude that **intersection** between a smaller and large dataset has performance difference and it is better to have the **smaller dataset** on the **left side** for faster execution for Scala set

Comment: The difference seem to be quite small given the huge size difference between the two sets. As the benchmark does not contain any warm-up and it performed from REPL, I would say it is inconclusive.

Comment: When I try this 100 Times I also get no conclusive answer.